# What is start up watts or amperage for 1/2 hp 7.1 amp Rheam Furnace?

Tags: furnace

What is start up watts or amperage for 1/2 hp 7.1 amp blower plus all componets  75,000 BTU Rheam RGPN-07eamer? What is running wattage?

Comment: Watts are amps times voltage.  Start up can be a few times running wattage for a few seconds.  For your example 7.1 amps will probably be maximum running at high.  7.1x120v = 852 watts, if running at high speed with everything else.

Comment: It isn't a specific multiple of current rating. You can experience 10x or more current if available during first voltage cycle (1/60th of a second), then reduced to LRA Locked Rotor Amperage until motor begins to spin. Sometimes the label or published specs will state LRA such as this similar Rheem motor https://www.supplyhouse.com/Rheem-51-24272-01-1-2-HP-1075RPM-3-Speed-48-Motor-120V

Comment: The electric utility can supply almost limitless current for motor startup.  So why care?

Comment: I have a feeling this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). It might be worth [edit]ing your question to ask what's really on your mind as opposed to asking about this specific thing. As @Harper-ReinstateMonica noted, the startup current will be available from the PoCo. Your breaker, assuming it's appropriately sized for the run load will allow for startup current for a few milliseconds before tripping, so that's not going to be an issue, either.